# Android: Restoring RecyclerView scrolling position with **offset** across application reinstallation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

We are storing `lastVisibleItemPosition` and `offset` in `firebase` and need to use those values when the user reinstalls the application so that we can redirect the user to the exact same position.

`lastVisibleItemPosition` is working fine but the problem is with `offset`.

Below is the code we are using to get `offset`.

```
recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()
```

Suppose the user was on the 9th item last time out of 10, then below is the code we are using to restore it once the user reinstalls and revisits the same screen again:

```
recyclerViewLayoutManager?.scrollToPositionWithOffset(9, offset)
```

However, it actually pushes down the 9th item by the `offset` value we have given and as a result, we are actually getting the 2nd item as a visible item.

We also tried `dy` that we get from `onScrolled` but it is changing its value from 0 to some positive number as we scroll and as we reach `RecyclerView.ScrollingState.IDLE`, it is becoming 0 again. So, maybe it is not what we want.

As per requirement, we are not allowed to use `snapHelper`.

We have also tried `scrollBy(x: Int, y: Int)` by passing `0` for `x` and saved `offset` as `y`. and it is also not giving the result we want.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

Currently, using the solution as provided in a comment. But the window is open for a better solution.

Comment: Maybe we can use ```layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition``` and calculate total offset using ```view.top```.

Comment: Yes! ```recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition)``` and then ```viewHolder.itemView.top``` worked!